# Object not being deleted from ListView

Tags: java, android-studio

I am creating a simple tasklist app in Android Studios.

I have two activities as following (removed imports and package specifications):

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    EditText taskAdd;
    Button add;
    public ListView tasks;
    public Integer pos = 0;
    public ArrayList<String> taskArray;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        taskAdd = findViewById(R.id.taskAdd);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        tasks = findViewById(R.id.tasks);
        taskArray = FileHelper.readData(this);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskArray);
        tasks.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        tasks.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.add:
                String entered = taskAdd.getText().toString();
                if (entered != "" || entered != null || entered != "null") {
                    adapter.add(entered);
                    taskAdd.setText("");

                    FileHelper.writeData(taskArray, this);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Task Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        pos = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        processExtraData();
    }
    private void processExtraData(){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int value = extras.getInt("Value");
            if (value == 1) {
                taskArray.remove(pos);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Task Removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pop.java (a popup)

```java
public class Pop extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button deleteButton;
    Button finishedButton;
    Button timerButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);
        deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.5),(int)(height*0.5));
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Value", 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

After I click deleteButton in Pop.java, processExtraData in MainActivity.java is supposed to run. The Toast does appear, but the selected object in the ListView is not deleted. No errors are thrown either. In addition, using Log.d to check the size of taskArray confirmed that this is not just a graphical issue. Why is this the case, and how should I go about fixing it?

Thank you for replying in advance.

Comment: Can you tell how you know that the object is not being removed from the list? If you do a System.out.println(taskArray.size()); before and after taskArray.remove(pos);, is it providing the same value? If not it is more likely to be a GUI updating issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! Using Log.d proved that pos is not being removed, and that this is not a GUI updating issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an object reference instead of a primitive data type, and so when you are calling taskArray.remove(pos), it is looking for pos the object rather than its denoted integer value.

Instead of:

```
taskArray.remove(pos);
```

try:

```
taskArray.remove(pos.intValue());
```